# How to convert a python c extension into a pure python ctypes module

Tags: python, ctypes

Does anyone have any experience porting python c extensions to a pure python ctypes module ? I would like to transition over to ironpython but want to start translating some c extensions or atleast parts of pywin32.  What are some things to be aware of before starting ?

Comment: "Pure Python" and "ctypes" don't belong next to each other.

Comment: @Ignacio: presumably, it's later easier to port a ctypes-based extension than an actual CPython extension

Comment: "porting python c extensions to a pure python ctypes module " does not make any sense

Comment: @Blackmoon and @ignacio: from the python docs: ctypes is a foreign function library for Python. It provides C compatible data types, and allows calling functions in DLLs or shared libraries. It can be used to wrap these libraries in pure Python. http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html

Comment: @Blackmoon and @ignacio: what's the problem with that? It's a pure python module alright, not a c extension, and it uses ctypes, hence it's a "pure python ctypes module". Regardless of whether you consider "pure" to mean that it has no other requirements than python itself, I think it's clear what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

[ctypesgen](http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/) seems interesting:  
this [post](http://mdqinc.com/blog/2011/07/automatic-sdl-bindings-for-python) analyzes use of ctypesgen vs [pycparser](http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/) for generating ctypes bindings to sdl.

Comment: Sure, but it has little to do with turning non-trivial C extensions into Python code.